# Wordpress site looks too big in chrome (in other browsers it's just fine)

Tags: wordpress

I have a `wordpress` site and when I open it on `chrome` it looks really really big, like the resolution is higher or like I have zoomed in the site (while the zoom is 100%). In other browsers it looks fine, as it supposed to be.

Here is how it's displayed in chrome:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBBXn.jpg

And here is how it's displayed in Firefox, as it supposed to be:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAQyW.jpg

It occurs in **every** chrome browser in **all** the computers and **not only in mine**..
I tried a lot of things and I don't know what else to do.
I don't know if it's something in the code (the css files) or in the wordpress settings...

Comment: And Command/Control + 0 won't set it back to a default zoom?

Comment: Nope.. It's already in the default zoom

Comment: Hey, @James - maybe try downloading "Chrome Canary", or disabling all extensions in your default Google Chrome and having a look (in incognito, too). My gut says that there's something going on with your browser, rather than the css.

Comment: @CameronHurd I don't know, I don't think that the problem is in the browser itself... It Happens in **every** chrome browser, not only in my computer.. I tried all what you said, but it isn't that.

Comment: Can you share more html/css or perhaps recreate in a codepen?

Comment: K then, here is the Custom CSS from the wordpress dashboard:
http://codepen.io/Jamess1/pen/yaRyYm

Comment: Shall I add any other code stuff? There are so many files that I don't know what to choose.. But I have access to all of them if you know which ones are relevant

Comment: Try and get the HTML & css of any page where the zoom is occurring into that codepen. When you've been able to recreate the chrome issue in the pen, we'll be able to debug much more effectively!

Comment: OK, I will try this, but it happens in all the pages so maybe the problem is in the theme files?

Comment: If it's a CSS issue, I suspect any page will do.

Comment: Listen, I don't know how to put it in codepen... I don't really know how all of those wordpress sites work.. There are only php files and every file "requires" another file. I don't have any clue of which css and php files are related together, and how to rebuild it in codepen..

Comment: What about linking to a public URL, is that an option? Else, try just hitting up "view source", and copypasting the HTML that the PHP files *generated*, since that's all that matters for you problem. :)

Comment: Yeah, right, it works now.. But the site is protected with  a password, and I prefer not to give it out here... maybe there's another way I can tell you privately what the password is?

Comment: You could DM me on twitter! @cameronhurd

Comment: OK, just started following you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening up your dev tools and filtering the css rules on `<html>` or `<body>` tags with "zoom".

[According to caniuse.com, no versions of Firefox or Opera Mini support the `zoom` property](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom), so it might be that chrome is just the only one respecting it, if that is indeed in your CSS somewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much again!